# DatabaseException - Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Results

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.appmaster.akash.messageplus, PID: 978
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.Results
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzear.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
     at com.appmaster.akash.messageplus.TakingQuizDone$1.onChildAdded(TakingQuizDone.java:65)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdri.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwu.zzbvb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxa.run(Unknown Source)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

Code

```
private void fetchResults() {
        mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(id).child("Quiz").child("Results").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Results results = dataSnapshot.getValue(Results.class);
                resultsList.add(results);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Database

[image]

Results.java

```
public class Results {
private String Name;
private String Score;

public Results() {
}

public Results(String Name, String Score) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Score = Score;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getScore() {
    return Score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    Score = score;
}
```

}

The error is in the database both the name and the value isn't fixed. Like its decided according to the user.

Saving the data

```
String name = RecieversName;
                HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put(name, String.valueOf(mScore));
                mRef.child("Users").child(RecieversId).child("Quiz").child("Results").setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(TakingQuiz.this, TakingQuizDone.class);
                            intent.putExtra("RecieversId",RecieversId);
                            intent.putExtra("Score", mScore.toString());
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to process all results under `.../Results` in one go. In that case you should use a `ValueEventListener` instead of a `ChildEventListener`.

In addition your `Results` class does not match the JSON data structure. This means that Firebase can't automatically read the properties of the JSON into a `Results` object when you call `getValue(Results.class)`. Instead you will have to do that conversion yourself.

```
mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(id).child("Quiz/Results").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot resultSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String user = resultSnapshot.getKey();
        String score = resultSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Results results = new Results(user, score);
        resultsList.add(results);
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  } 

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      throw databaseError.toException();
  }
})
```

Comment: How willl it populate the recyclerview then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. You have an adapter, and then call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you changed the data set of that adapter (which I assume `resultsList` is).

Comment: does my adapter match the database... like is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you database structure, under a `Results` node it seems (if I understand correctly) that you have a node with a name corresponding to the user's Name and the value of this node corresponding to the Score.

With regards to your `Results.java` class your database should have the data organized as follows:

```
-Quiz
  -Question1
  -.......
  -Results
    -Name: "Akash"
    -Score: "5"
```

Comment: Cant i just use Akash : 5 instead of Name Akash Score 5?

Comment: Yes you can, but then you have to follow the recommendations of Frank in the other answer. And stop using the Results class.